# Replacement for NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.Configure.SagasWereFound

Tags: persistence, nservicebus, saga

Upgrading NServiceBus from version 3 to 4 and get this error while compiling:

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Impl' does not exist in the namespace 'NServiceBus.Sagas' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
    if (NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.Configure.SagasWereFound)
        {
            var connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"];

            // Register session factory which takes care of managing
            // the database connections and transactions


    Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent(typeof(OracleSagaSessionFactory),   
    DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall)
                .ConfigureProperty("ConnectionString", connStr);

            // Then register the saga persister itself

    Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent(typeof(OracleSagaPersister), 
    DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
NServiceBus.Features.Feature.IsEnabled<Features.Sagas>()
```